# Determine the big $O$ notation

Tags: asymptotics

For $\epsilon>0$, why the following holds with $x$ larger enough
$$O(x^{-\epsilon/2}\log x)=O(2^{-\log^{1/2}x})$$

Answer (score 0):

All you need is
$\log(x) = o(x^c)$ for any
$c > 0$.

Taking logs of the question,
this gives
$-c \log(x)$ on the left where we can choose
$c = \epsilon/4$
and $-d \log^{1/2}(x)$ on the right
for some $d > 0$
and this makes it clear since
$\log(x) \to \infty$.

Comment: I took logs of the left, i got $-\epsilon/2\log x +\log\log x$. How to get the term $-c\log(x)$, $c=\epsilon/4$?

Comment: The log log doesn't matter since it's small. And to get the c log x use the result in my first line.

Comment: The right hand side is $-\epsilon/2\log x$ (if we ignore the term $\log\log x$), and the left hand side we have $-d\log^{1/2} (x)$ for some $d>0$. Is it suffices to conclude that $O(x^{-\epsilon/2}\log x)=O(2^{-\log^{1/2}x})$ with $\log(x)\rightarrow \infty$? Sorry, I can't understand why we choose $c=\epsilon/4$.